# How to output the number of iterations needed to find a value in a BST?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I can't seem to make my program that implements a Binary Search Tree (using User input) and search for a value, to print out the number of iterations that were necessary to actually find this value.
I've created a method called 'getLastIterationCount()' that returns the number of iterations but when I want to print it out in my main method, I get an error on the line 'System.out.println(getLastIterationCount());'. I think that my method is not in the right place but I'm not sure whats missing. Any ideas how I could make this program work?

```
     /* Class Node */
class Node  


{
 Node left, right;
 int data;



 /* Constructor */
 public Node(int n)
 {
     left = null;
     right = null;
     data = n;
 }         

/* Function to get data from node */
public int getData() 
{
    return data;
}

 /* Function to get left node */
public Node getLeft() 
{
    return left;
}

/* Function to get right node */
public Node getRight()
{
    return right;
  }
 }

 /* Class BST */
 class BST

{

 private Node root;
 private int iterations;
 /* Constructor */
 public BST()
 {
     root = null;
 }
 /* Functions to insert data */
 public void insert(int data)
 {
     root = insert(root, data);
 }
 /* Function to insert data recursively */
 private Node insert(Node node, int data)
 {
     if (node == null)
         node = new Node(data);
     else
     {
         if (data <= node.data)
             node.left = insert(node.left, data);
         else
             node.right = insert(node.right, data);
     }
     return node;
 }


  /* Functions to search for an element */
public boolean search(int val) 
{
    iterations=0;
    iterations++;
    return search(root, val);
}



/* Function to search for an element recursively */
private boolean search(Node r, int val) 
{
    iterations=0;
    boolean found = false;
    while ((r != null) && !found) 
    {
        int rval = r.getData();
        if (val < rval){
            r = r.getLeft();
        }

        else if (val > rval){   
            r = r.getRight();
        }

        else 
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        found = search(r, val);

    }

    return found;
}

   public int getLastIterationCount(){
   return iterations;
   }


  }
   /* Class LinkedListBST */
   public class LinkedListBST
  {


 public static void main(String[] args)

 {  


     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     /* Creating object of BST */
     BST bst = new BST(); 
     System.out.println("Linked List Binary Search Tree Test\n");          
     char ch;
     /*  Accept input  */
     do    
     {
         System.out.println("Enter integer element to insert");
         bst.insert( scan.nextInt() );                     



         System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue (Type y or n) \n");
         ch = scan.next().charAt(0);  


     } while (ch == 'Y'|| ch == 'y');   
     System.out.println("\nEnter an element to be searched: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Search result : " + bst.search(sc.nextInt()));

    System.out.println(getLastIterationCount()); //ISSUE IS HERE

    sc.close();

   }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the method `getLastIterationCount()`without the object. Please call it using `bst.getLastIterationCount()`

Answer (score 0):

I think your search code is already close to being correct.  First, initialize the counter at the external entry point to search:

```
public boolean search(int val) {
    iterations = 1;
    return search(root, val);
}
```

Then, at each call to the private internal search method, increment the counter by one:

```
private boolean search(Node r, int val) {
    ++iterations;     // increment counter by one for current iteration

    boolean found = false;
    while ((r != null) && !found) {
        int rval = r.getData();
        if (val < rval){
            r = r.getLeft();
        }
        else if (val > rval) {
            r = r.getRight();
        }
        else {
            found = true;
            break;
        }

        found = search(r, val);
    }

    return found;
}
```

I have assumed here that you want the number of recursive calls necessary to find the value.  If instead you wanted the height at which an item was found, it is a different question.

**Edit:**

I noticed that you have a getter method for returning the count.  It is an instance method and you should therefore call it as such:

```
bst.getLastIterationCount()
```

Comment: I've followed your advice, thank you but it looks like that my 'System.out.println(getLastIterationCount());' has been underlined as wrong by Netbeans. Is my method 'getLastIterationCount()' in the wrong place, thus preventing my print statement to recognize the call to function?

Comment: Hello See my answer below and try that !

Comment: @humanbeing Yes, you need to call `bst.getLastIterationCount()` to get the count for a particular tree instance.  But I also think the bigger problem was with your counting logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the method using the object bst that you have instantiated as below :

```
bst.getLastIterationCount();
```

Comment: Please don't advertise your answer by commenting under other answers.

Comment: I was pointing him to my answer to resolve the issue that he had mentioned, I don't know if it is an advertise, I haven't spoken anything irrelevant !

Comment: You were right, but this is only part of the problem.